# how to set trainable param in concatenated keras models

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

The original code is too bg so I will try to explain the issue with a simplified example.

First, import the libraries we need:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
```

Then load a pretrained model and print out the summary.

```
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
model.summary()
```

Here is the output of "summary":

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 224, 224, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)       (None, 230, 230, 3)  0           input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)                  (None, 112, 112, 64) 9472        conv1_pad[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn_conv1 (BatchNormalization)   (None, 112, 112, 64) 256         conv1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 112, 112, 64) 0           bn_conv1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 55, 55, 64)   0           activation_1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch2a (Conv2D)         (None, 55, 55, 64)   4160        max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2a_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, 55, 55, 64)   256         res2a_branch2a[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)       (None, 55, 55, 64)   0           bn2a_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, 55, 55, 64)   36928       activation_2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2a_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, 55, 55, 64)   256         res2a_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)       (None, 55, 55, 64)   0           bn2a_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, 55, 55, 256)  16640       activation_3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch1 (Conv2D)          (None, 55, 55, 256)  16640       max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2a_branch2c (BatchNormalizati (None, 55, 55, 256)  1024        res2a_branch2c[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2a_branch1 (BatchNormalizatio (None, 55, 55, 256)  1024        res2a_branch1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_1 (Add)                     (None, 55, 55, 256)  0           bn2a_branch2c[0][0]              
                                                                 bn2a_branch1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)       (None, 55, 55, 256)  0           add_1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2b_branch2a (Conv2D)         (None, 55, 55, 64)   16448       activation_4[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2b_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, 55, 55, 64)   256         res2b_branch2a[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)       (None, 55, 55, 64)   0           bn2b_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2b_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, 55, 55, 64)   36928       activation_5[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2b_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, 55, 55, 64)   256         res2b_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)       (None, 55, 55, 64)   0           bn2b_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2b_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, 55, 55, 256)  16640       activation_6[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2b_branch2c (BatchNormalizati (None, 55, 55, 256)  1024        res2b_branch2c[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_2 (Add)                     (None, 55, 55, 256)  0           bn2b_branch2c[0][0]              
                                                                 activation_4[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_7 (Activation)       (None, 55, 55, 256)  0           add_2[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2c_branch2a (Conv2D)         (None, 55, 55, 64)   16448       activation_7[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2c_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, 55, 55, 64)   256         res2c_branch2a[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_8 (Activation)       (None, 55, 55, 64)   0           bn2c_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2c_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, 55, 55, 64)   36928       activation_8[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2c_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, 55, 55, 64)   256         res2c_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_9 (Activation)       (None, 55, 55, 64)   0           bn2c_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2c_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, 55, 55, 256)  16640       activation_9[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2c_branch2c (BatchNormalizati (None, 55, 55, 256)  1024        res2c_branch2c[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_3 (Add)                     (None, 55, 55, 256)  0           bn2c_branch2c[0][0]              
                                                                 activation_7[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_10 (Activation)      (None, 55, 55, 256)  0           add_3[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res3a_branch2a (Conv2D)         (None, 28, 28, 128)  32896       activation_10[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn3a_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, 28, 28, 128)  512         res3a_branch2a[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_11 (Activation)      (None, 28, 28, 128)  0           bn3a_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res3a_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, 28, 28, 128)  147584      activation_11[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn3a_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, 28, 28, 128)  512         res3a_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_12 (Activation)      (None, 28, 28, 128)  0           bn3a_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res3a_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, 28, 28, 512)  66048       activation_12[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res3a_branch1 (Conv2D)          (None, 28, 28, 512)  131584      activation_10[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn3a_branch2c (BatchNormalizati (None, 28, 28, 512)  2048        res3a_branch2c[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn3a_branch1 (BatchNormalizatio (None, 28, 28, 512)  2048        res3a_branch1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_4 (Add)                     (None, 28, 28, 512)  0           bn3a_branch2c[0][0]              
                                                                 bn3a_branch1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_13 (Activation)      (None, 28, 28, 512)  0           add_4[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res3b_branch2a (Conv2D)         (None, 28, 28, 128)  65664       activation_13[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn3b_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, 28, 28, 128)  512         res3b_branch2a[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_14 (Activation)      (None, 28, 28, 128)  0           bn3b_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res3b_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, 28, 28, 128)  147584      activation_14[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

(I cut the output of `summary()` function to save some space.)
Right now, all layer parameters are trainable. For the sake of example, I set one **trainable** parameter to `False` as following.

```
model.get_layer('bn5c_branch2c').trainable = False
```

Right now, all layers are still trainable except the layer **bn5c_branch2c**.

Next, create a new model using this original model but let it be a concatenated one.

```
in1 = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name="in1")
in2 = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name="in2")

out1 = model(in1)
out2 = model(in2)

new_model = Model(inputs=[in1, in2], outputs=[out1, out2])
```

And print out the summary again:

```
new_model.summary()
```

And the output:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
in1 (InputLayer)                (None, 224, 224, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
in2 (InputLayer)                (None, 224, 224, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
resnet50 (Model)                (None, 1000)         25636712    in1[0][0]                        
                                                                 in2[0][0]                        
==================================================================================================
Total params: 25,636,712
Trainable params: 25,583,592
Non-trainable params: 53,120
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

At this point, I have lost my ability to see which layers are trainable and not trainable because all layers of the original ResNet50 model is now shown as one single layer.
And if I run the following code, it gives me `True`:

```
new_model.get_layer('resnet50').trainable    # Returns True
```

**Question 1)** I did set the trainable parameter of layer **bn5c_branch2c** to False above in the **model**. May I assume that the trainable value of **bn5c_branch2c** is still False even in new_model?

**Question 2)** If the answer is yes to the above question (meaning that the trainable param value of layer **bn5c_branch2c** is still False in the new_model)... And if I later save this new_model's architecture and weights, and load them again to further train this new_model... May I trust that the trainable param value of **bn5c_branch2c** will remain False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** you can access the layers of a model using `.layers[idx]` property where `idx` is the index of the layer in the model (starting from zero). Alternatively, if you have set names for the layers you can access them using `.get_layer(layer_name)` method.

**A1)** Yes, you can confirm this by:

```
print(new_model.layers[2].get_layer('bn5c_branch2c').trainable) # output: False
```

Also, you can confirm this by looking at the number of non-trainable parameters in the summary of the model.

**A2)** Yes, you can confirm this by:

```
# save it
new_model.save('my_new_model.hd5')

# load it again
new_model = load_model('my_new_model.hd5')

print(new_model.layers[2].get_layer('bn5c_branch2c').trainable) # output: False
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. I did not know that I could reach the parameter in the way you showed in your answer. Solved!